Breakpoints getting skipped while debugging Raylib 5.0 C++ code built with Makefile in Neovim with DAP using CodeLLDB
I am currently working on a C++ project using Raylib 5.0 and I’m building it with a Makefile. I’m using Neovim, with DAP and DAP UI for debugging, and CodeLLDB as the debugger. However, I have an issue where my breakpoints are always getting rejected and the debugger doesn’t stop at the breakpoints. after doing dap continue function to start the debugger the B(breakpoint symbol) changes to R(rejected)
Note: I know the BUILD_MODE set to RELEASE but that is not a problem because i did set the -g flag. also i tried to use the DEBUG mode and same result.
Here is my Makefile:
.PHONY: all clean

# Define required raylib variables
PROJECT_NAME       ?= game
RAYLIB_VERSION     ?= 5.0
RAYLIB_PATH        ?= C:\raylib\raylib

# Define compiler path on Windows
COMPILER_PATH      ?= C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin

PLATFORM           ?= PLATFORM_DESKTOP

DESTDIR ?= /usr/local
RAYLIB_INSTALL_PATH ?= $(DESTDIR)/lib
RAYLIB_H_INSTALL_PATH ?= $(DESTDIR)/include

RAYLIB_LIBTYPE        ?= STATIC
BUILD_MODE            ?= RELEASE
USE_EXTERNAL_GLFW     ?= FALSE
USE_WAYLAND_DISPLAY   ?= FALSE

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
        PLATFORM_OS=WINDOWS
        export PATH := $(COMPILER_PATH):$(PATH)
    endif
endif

RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH     ?= $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src
EXAMPLE_RUNTIME_PATH   ?= $(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)

CC = g++
MAKE = mingw32-make

CFLAGS += -g -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces

ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),DEBUG)
    CFLAGS += -g -O0
else
    CFLAGS += -s -O1
endif

LDFLAGS = -L.

ifneq ($(wildcard $(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)/.*),)
    LDFLAGS += -L$(RAYLIB_RELEASE_PATH)
endif
ifneq ($(wildcard $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/.*),)
    LDFLAGS += -L$(RAYLIB_PATH)/src
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),WINDOWS)
        LDLIBS = -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
    endif
endif

SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = obj

SRCS = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: $(PROJECT_NAME)

$(PROJECT_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(RAYLIB_PATH)/src/raylib.rc.data -o $(PROJECT_NAME) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -D$(PLATFORM)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -D$(PLATFORM) -c $< -o $@

clean:
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),PLATFORM_DESKTOP)
    ifeq ($(PLATFORM_OS),WINDOWS)
        del *.o *.exe /s
    endif
endif
    @echo Cleaning done


And here is the output of the make command:
PS C:\Users\userx\OneDrive\Documents\Development\C++\raylib-test> make
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -s -O1  -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -c src/Game.cpp -o src/Game.o
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -s -O1  -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -c src/GameObject.cpp -o src/GameObject.o
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -s -O1  -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -c src/Map.cpp -o src/Map.o
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -s -O1  -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -c src/Player.cpp -o src/Player.o
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -s -O1  -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -c src/Vector2D.cpp -o src/Vector2D.o
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -s -O1  -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -c src/main.cpp -o src/main.o
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++14 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wno-missing-braces -s -O1 C:\raylib\raylib/src/raylib.rc.data -o game src/Game.o src/GameObject.o src/Map.o src/Player.o src/Vector2D.o src/main.o  -L. -LC:\raylib\raylib/src -LC:\raylib\raylib/src -lraylib -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP


this is the main file of my source code :
#include "raylib.h"
#include "Game.hpp"
int main(void)

    const int screenWidth = 1024; //breakpoint here (just to test)
    const int screenHeight = 512;
    Game *game=new Game();
    game->init((char *)"RAYCAST", screenWidth, screenHeight);

    SetTargetFPS(60);             
                                  
    
    while (!WindowShouldClose())   
    {
        game->update();
        game->render();
    }

    CloseWindow();      
    return 0;
}

I’m not sure why the breakpoints are not working. am i doing something wrong in makefile that cause this problem? or what ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I tried the Debugger with simple C++ project with two .cpp files and one .hpp file. i built it with Makefile and the debugger works (stops on breakpoints). so maybe the problem with my Makefile?

I don't see your source code here and where you are putting the break point, but if I were to guess (because this has happened to me in Visual Studio) some line of code you think is executing might be getting optimized away by your compiler. This is true for example in cases where the compiler knows what an outcome of a conditional statement will be or if another thread will act on it (but the compiler doesn't know this). You may want to read up on the "Volatile" keyword.

@Valdez I put my main.cpp source code in the post above, But i don't think the problem is because of the compiler because i set the breakpoint on const int screenWidth = 1024; and this line can't be optimized more to be removed.

Probably off topic but... (char *)"RAYCAST" sets off all kinds of alarm bells.  Does Game::init attempt to modify that parameter?

@G.M. no Game::init don't change this parameter is just use (char *)"RAYCAST" to set the title of the window

I Solved it by simply using CMake to generate Makefile with build type equal to debug. By writing this line in CMake:set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
